# Why some image url is not working with image tag?

Tags: react-native

I have two image url.

First one is

`https://movies.tw.campaign.yahoo.net/i/o/production/movies/April2018/BkglQJA9PKZSJ7QfyWfM-500x714.jpg`

The second is

`http://imgs.cdn.speranze.tw/uploaded%2Fstudio%2Fcinema%2Fdefault%2F1000010%2F1000026%2F1003866%2F12058_n.jpg?w=800&h=534&p=lt`

Both of them paste in web site can show image.

But when i use them in react native `<Image />`

First one is working, but the second url i just get an empty image.

Why ? I can't figure it out.

I use like this:

```
<Image 
      source={{ uri: 'http://imgs.cdn.speranze.tw/uploaded%2Fstudio%2Fcinema%2Fdefault%2F1000010%2F1000026%2F1003866%2F12058_n.jpg?w=800&h=534&p=lt' }} 
      style={{ height: 100, width: 300 }} 
    />
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my class componet code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

class TicketInformation extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Image 
          source={{ uri: 'https://movies.tw.campaign.yahoo.net/i/o/production/movies/April2018/BkglQJA9PKZSJ7QfyWfM-500x714.jpg' }} 
          style={{ height: 100, width: 300 }} 
        />

        <Image 
          source={{ uri: 'http://imgs.cdn.speranze.tw/uploaded%2Fstudio%2Fcinema%2Fdefault%2F1000010%2F1000026%2F1003866%2F12058_n.jpg?w=800&h=534&p=lt' }} 
          style={{ height: 100, width: 300 }} 
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default TicketInformation;
```

My screen shows like this:
[image]

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MovieToGo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "jest-react-native": "^18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!native-base)/"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "0.0.14",
    "@shoutem/ui": "^0.23.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.17",
    "native-base": "^2.4.5",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.4",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-multi-slider": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-youtube": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "teaset": "^0.5.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, insert the context because the images are loading normally: https://snack.expo.io/HJcqZZzbQ

Comment: Are there errors in your console?  Does one have a content-policy?

Comment: My guess would be the encoded URL. Some [issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16744) seems to indicate it too. You might want to try to convert it to Base64

Comment: I have show my class component code in my question, it still shows first image.
@zero298 There is no any error message in my console. I'm not sure how to check content-policy from url.

Do you mean change the url from Base64 ?

Comment: @FabianoLothor Strange... Why you can show both of them, but i can't...

Comment: @FabianoLothor If i cope and paste your code i still only can see first image.

Comment: @徐博俊 please, show us your package.json

Comment: @FabianoLothor Sure , i  have updated my package.json in my question.

Comment: I find the solution finally. I have to set permission for ios in `info.plist` file.